RPi not turning GPIO pin off causing the relay to remain on
I am a complete newbie here. I bought RPi, flashed the OS. I also bought 5v relay. I have connected the 2nd pin to VCC of the relay, 6th pin to GND of the relay, 40th pin to the 'IN' point of the relay. At present I have not connected anything to the other side of the relay (but the problem also exists if I connect a load of led). Also no other changes have been made to the RPi except the SSH connection enablement and software update using sudo apt get commands i.e RPi is almost at factory settings.
My Code:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

in1 = 21 //i.e 40th pin 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(in1, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.HIGH) //1
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW) //2
    print("inside try after low") //3
    time.sleep(1)
      
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup() //4

My problem:
Once the relay turns high at comment //1 it does not turns off at point //2. I kill the program using 'control + c' then it turns off which is not what I desire. I just want it to turn on and then turn off. The point //3  does get executed. //4 executes when ctrl+c pressed. If I remove cleanup code and do not press ctrl+c then the relay's green light remains turned on continuously.
P.S This is raspberry pi 64bit OS


Relays are normally ON when given 0V (LOW) and OFF when given  3.3V (HIGH). Check the specification of the relay board.

Does this answer your question? Can you use a 5V Relay Module with the Pi?

@CoderMike relays are on when powered. Crummy, poorly designed relay modules are another matter.

I have added the image of the relay. I will go through the link though I am not sure if I would grasp it as I don't have enough knowledge.

Connecting the vcc of the relay to 3.3v of the RPi worked. I am not sure if this is the solution for this.

A picture of a relay module is meaningless. You need to post a circuit. This looks like a different module to most but attempting to control a 5V relay with 3.3V is unpredictable.

@Milliways I have highlighted the connection part of the RPi. Besides this only monitor, mouse, Keyboard connections exists. No load has been given to relay as just I need to check the switching ON/Off part of the relay.

Without details of WHAT IS CONNECTED anything else is irrelevant. From the blurry out of focus photo you posted this appears to have a transistor and if this is a PNP with a common 5V rail (like the device in the duplicate) it won't work without additional circuitry. I don't understand why so many of these cheap Chinese devices do this. If they used a NPN transistor (which uses the same number of components) it would work with both Pi & Arduino.

I also bought 5v relay. ... no, you didn't... you bought a 5 V relay module ... a relay is one of the components in the module

Connecting the vcc of the relay to 3.3v of the RPi caused the relay to turn off correctly. I am not sure if this is the solution for this.

Couple of cmts I'll make here as the space under your question have gotten a bit crowded: 1. It always best to refer to pins by their GPIO designation - rather than their physical position on the header. See Raspberry Pi Pinout as a guide. 2. From the photo you've added, it's clear that your relay is marked for operation at 5V, and therefore the problem is most likely in your software. If I were in your shoes, I'd use GPIO 17 (or 22, 23, 24, 27) for my output. Finally, "in1 = 29 //i.e 40th pin" in your code looks incorrect; pin #40 is not GPIO29

It was a typo. Fixed it. In the code I had used 21. Still the problem persisted.

@Seamus any reason for suggesting other pins but not GPIO21 ?

PLEASE NOTE: I do not use RPi.GPIO; I cannot comment on your code. But to your Q: GPIO21 is a "specialty pin" (my terminology). When I use a GPIO for turning things OFF & ON, I favor the "straightforward" (my terminology) pins; i.e. pins that don't have a special purpose.

Thanks for answering @Seamus
